# Manejo de Clipboard con Java y Windows superior a V1803

Tags: java, windows, windows10

Antes que nada un gran saludo a la comunidad de StackOverflow.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cual necesito hacer uso o manejo del clipboard del sistema.
Para ello estoy utilizando las siguientes líneas de código:

```
StringSelection texto = new StringSelection("String");
Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
cb.setContents(texto, texto);
```

Al hacer click en un determinado botón, se ejecuta el código anterior y me copia el string correspondiente al clipboard del sistema.

Esto me funciona de manera correcta en mi computador con Windows 10 V1803 y versiones anteriores.

El problema radica en versiones superiores de Sistema Operativo, Windows 10 V1909 en adelante, en este caso el contenido copiado al clipboard no queda disponible para ser utilizado con **Ctrl+V** o el menú contextual de **Pegar**, es decir al hacer **Ctrl+V** el contenido del clipboard es vacío o errado (contenido viejo).

Si me pueden ayudar con esto se los agradecería!

Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Por qué fijas el owner del `SetContents` con el mismo valor de la cadena? Normalmente lo ve uno asociado a null o a this para que el mismo proceso lo encuentre. Lo otro: de qué tamaño es la cadena? Puede que no te este alcanzando el heap asignado.

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, he fijado el owner a **null** y a **this** obteniendo el mismo comportamiento. El  string que se copia al clipboard es una contraseña de máximo 15 caracteres entre letras, números y caracteres especiales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con respecto a mi pregunta, al final me di cuenta que el detalle era un error de concepto de mi parte, esto debido a que la aplicación que estoy montando es Web y el código empleado para el manejo del clipboard se ejecutaba del lado del servidor, por tal motivo modifique el código para trabarjarlo con Js del lado del cliente y asunto resuelto.